# Qthreading and signal emiting from it

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5, qt-creator

`doit` is a `Qthread` subclass with a `signal` `kif()` but the signal emitting is not working I want to show the resualt of `gav()` on one of my `editLines` at the same time as its changes inside `gav()` pls help :((((((( I wasted so much time to find out how I can do it :((((((

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

doit.h

```
#ifndef DOIT_H
#define DOIT_H
#include <QThread>

class doit : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    doit();
    int i;
    QString z;
    void run() ;
    void gav(int &i);
signals:
    void kif(const QString &text);
};

#endif // DOIT_H
```

```
#include "doit.h"

doit::doit()
{

}

void doit::run()
{
    gav(i);
}

void doit::gav(int &i) 
{
    int k=i;
    for (int b=0;b<k;b++){
        i=b;
        z= QString::number(i);
        emit kif(z);
    }
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "doit.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    doit *dovit=new doit;
private slots:
    void checkInput(const QString &text);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   //QObject::connect(dovit,doit::kif(&QString),this , MainWindow::checkInput(QString)))
   connect(dovit,SIGNAL(kif(QString)),this,SLOT(checkInput(QString)));
   dovit->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::checkInput(const QString &text)
{
    ui->lineEdit_3->setText(text);
}
```

and Im new in this , so pls tell me exactlly where should I change or add and what tanx alot

Comment: I think your `connect(dovit,SIGNAL(kif(QString),this,SLOT(checkInput(QString)));` is wong because of the const QString& but I am not 100% sure. While I still code in the Qt4 connect style  (have legacy projects that are 10+ years old) I don't think I use reference parameters often.

Comment: @drescherjm tnx for comment but that wasnt the problem i correct it still nothing (ps. i get errors both inside doit.cpp and mainwindow.cpp

Comment: ***i get errors both inside doit.cpp and mainwindow.cpp***  What errors? If you have an error message add the exact text of the message.

Comment: error: undefined reference to `doit::kif(QString const&)'           :-1: error: debug/doit.o:doit.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTV4doit[.refptr._ZTV4doit]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for doit'

Comment: Was moc run on the code?

Comment: @drescherjm what do you mean by moc?? (ps.if i comment the signal and connect it work but wont do what i want)

Comment: `moc` is an external program that is run that generates code for the signals and slots ... [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html)

Comment: @drescherjm I just created a signal slot between 2 line edit inside the mainwindow, and commented everything related to my signal inside doit and its worked so I think yes

Comment: See if that fixed the linker error. You may have needed to force moc to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it finally worked after wasting a lot of my time. For anyone wondering `vtables` was the problem (as I read its a bug (not sure)) and I should just

> right click on the project folder and  **rebuild** and **run qmake** the project ,

- I added  `Qobject.h` too and it worked.

working code:

(it is also a simple and good example of meta signaling in qt if you need it)

doit.h

```
#define DOIT_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>


class doit : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    doit();

    void gav();
    void run() ;
signals:

    void kif(QString text);

};

#endif // DOIT_H
```

doit.cpp

```
#include "doit.h"
#include <QDebug>

doit::doit()
{

}

void doit::run()
{
    gav();
}


void doit::gav()
{
    QString z;
    for (int i=0;i<11;i++){
        z="mamad";
        z = z + QString::number(i);
        QThread::sleep(1);
        qDebug()<<z;
        emit kif(z);
    }
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "doit.h"


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    doit *dovit=new doit;
    //doit dovit;
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(dovit,SIGNAL(kif(QString)),this->ui->lineEdit_3,SLOT(setText(QString)));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    dovit->start();
}
```